# JPanel being repainted when resizing JFrame although its not obscured or resized

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jsplitpane

I was testing a game im writing when i discovered one of the JPanels inside the JSplitPane was being repainted when the JFrame was being resized even though its area was not being obscured nor was it resized.

Although logic, (more specifically, counters) should never be put inside a paintComponent method, it does raise potentially serious problems.

Has anyone encountered/noticed this behaviour?  I've read one way of preventing repaints is to use the RepaintManager.markCompletlyClean(JComponent).  Any suggestions/workarounds other than RepaintManager?  Is it a bug?

See below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
                jframe.setLocation(100,100);
                jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel jpanel1 = new JPanel()
                {
                    final static long serialVersionUID = 0;

                    int int_repaints = 0;

                    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
                    {
                        System.out.println("repainting jpanel1=" + (int_repaints++));
                    }

                    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
                    {
                        return new Dimension(300,300);
                    }
                };

                JPanel jpanel2 = new JPanel()
                {
                    final static long serialVersionUID = 0;

                    int int_repaints = 0;

                    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
                    {
                        System.out.println("repainting jpanel2=" + (int_repaints++));
                    }

                    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
                    {
                        return new Dimension(300,300);
                    }
                };

                JSplitPane jsplitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,jpanel1,jpanel2);

                jframe.setContentPane(jsplitPane);
                jframe.pack();
                jframe.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? you don't want to repaint the jpanel??

Comment: It is not a problem. Swing determines when a component needs to be repainted. `Although logic, (more specifically, counters) should never be put inside a paintComponent method` - Exactly. The painting methods should only be for painting. There is no need for a workaround because this is normal behaviour.

Comment: the problem is, why is it being repainted even though its not obscured nor resized?  try it.  resize the jframe using the right border.  notice the left component of the splitpane doesnt change size and yet it gets repainted.

Comment: @camickr, "normal behaviour"?  it appears wasteful.  there is no need to repaint a component if it doesnt need repainting.  btw, have you noticed this before?

Comment: Yes I have noticed it, because it is normal behaviour. The split pane is resized so all its child components are repainted. When a component is repainted the method `paintChildren` is invoked to paint the children. It does not invoke `only paint some of the children`. Painting is a hierarchical process. Once the parent component needs be paint `ALL` of the children will be repainted. Don't try to micro manage the painting subsystem.